# Make startup script which automatically Runs in Administrator Mode for deployment purposes - Windows 11

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, deployment, runas

I am deploying Windows 11 via the Network.
The process is the following:

1. Load the image via winpe on the SSD of every machine with the dism tool.
2. Load a startup script on the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\startup.bat` script which would add some extra configurations and software which are more up do date (in silent mode)

After the deployment and the reboot, the setup logs in as the administrator account which is of course "active" and starts the `startup.bat` script, but he problem is that cmd doesn't start as administrator (Everything or almost everything is being blocked because the cmd environment has no rights to do anything), and I get a lot off access is denied errors linked to the net use commands
which can only run as admin.

---

With windows 11

[image: CMD not as admin]

---

With Windows 10:

This is what I get in Windows 10 with the exact same deyployment type (dism, put cmd in the startup folder and let it execute at startup.)
So what this does is that it installs all the software correctly without any righs assignment issues (The net use (network) commands work perfectly)

[image: CMD as Admin]

I've already got a workaround with the deployment xml which I put in the `C:\Windows\Panther\unattend.xml` where I insert all of my scripts one after the other in the :

```
 <FirstLogonCommands>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add"><Order>1</Order><CommandLine>C:\script1.bat</CommandLine><Description>RunOnce Command</Description></SynchronousCommand>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add"><Order>2</Order><CommandLine>c:\script2.bat</CommandLine><Description>RunOnce Command</Description></SynchronousCommand>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add"><Order>3</Order><CommandLine>etc..</CommandLine><Description>RunOnce Command</Description></SynchronousCommand>
    <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add"><Order>4</Order><CommandLine>__RUNONCE4__</CommandLine><Description>RunOnce Command</Description></SynchronousCommand>
 </FirstLogonCommands>
```

But the thing is that I would need to change all the deployment process with windows 11 compared to windows 10. And There are some installs which require a restart before continuing another installation, by putting a new script in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\xyz.bat` after the old one has finished its tasks.

My question is quite simple: Is there a way to make cmd start automatically as administrator just by starting cmd  or starting a script in the startup folder? I've already tried a lot of quick fixes like reg files like this one and a lot of other Rag entries. But non of them make actualy Cmd start as admin by doucle clicking on the file. It can also be that windows 11 does not allow this anymore, which is fine.. I would take the workarounds. Any Ideas would be highly appreciated.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"="RUNASADMIN"
```